# Количество ссылок на кешируемые объекты

Tags: python, python-3.x

В данный момент пытаюсь изучать python по книге Мартка Лутца. В одной из глав он рассказывает про типизацию и про разделяемые ссылки. Он пишет что некоторые объекты заранее кешированны, дабы частые числа и строки не создавались в угоду оптимизации. Мне не понятно вот что, при вызове функции sys.getrefcount(0) моя среда pyCharm даёт ответ 173 и мне в принцыпе понятно что это значит, но если в кач-ве параметра передать иное значение, например число 1234127832.11101, то ответ от функции будет равным 3. Я не понимаю откуда именно это число, ведь должно быть как 1, так как этот объект используется единожды. Прошу помочь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одна ссылка для константы, одна ссылка для аргумента передаваемого в `getrefcount` и ещё одну создаёт компилятор в процессе работы.

Comment: Благодарю. А где можно прочитать поглубже об этой теме?

Comment: Не уверен, что есть какой-то централизованный источник по внутреннему устройству Python, если не считать исходников CPython. Разве что [эта недописанная книжка](https://leanpub.com/insidethepythonvirtualmachine) и разбросанные по всему интернету статьи. Например, в [этом блоге](https://tech.blog.aknin.name/category/my-projects/pythons-innards/) много толковых публикаций о кишочках CPython.